# row-wise operation using function in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a function like this:

```
  def number(row):
        if row['temp'] == '1 Person':
            return 'One'
        elif row['temp'] == '2 Persons':
            return 'Two'
        elif row['temp'] == '3 Persons':
            return 'Three'
        elif row['temp'] in ['4 Persons','5 Persons', '6 Persons', '7 Persons','8 Persons',
            '9 Persons','10 Persons','11 Persons']:
            return 'More'
        else:
            return None
```

Now, I want to change the values in my data frame looping through row-wise.

How can I loop through my data frame and replace the values according to the function above in Pyspark?

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a sample data frame with the data

   ```
    df_row = spark.createDataFrame(
    [("1 Person", "2", "3"),("2 Persons", "2", "3"),
     ("3 Persons", "2", "3"),("4 Persons", "2", "3"),
     ("5 Persons", "2", "3"),("6 Persons", "2", "3"),
     ("7 Persons", "2", "3"),("8 Persons", "2", "3"),
     ("9 Persons", "2", "3")],
     schema=['temp', 'col2', 'col3']
    )
   ```
2. Define the function and also create the UDF function

   ```
    def number(row):
        if row == '1 Person':
            return 'One'
        elif row == '2 Persons':
            return 'Two'
        elif row == '3 Persons':
            return 'Three'
        elif row in ['4 Persons','5 Persons', '6 Persons', '7 Persons','8 Persons',
            '9 Persons','10 Persons','11 Persons']:
            return 'More'
        else:
            return None

    numberUDF = udf(lambda z: number(z),StringType())
   ```
3. Rewrite the column function 'temp'

   ```
    df_row = df_row.withColumn('temp',numberUDF(col('temp')))
   ```

Please check the below output:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HBUjS.png)

Answer (score 1):

The Python function can (almost identical) be translated into a native [SQL statement](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/api/sql/index.html#when):

```python
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df.withColumn('result', 
    F.expr("""case
                when temp == '1 Person' then 'One'
                when temp == '2 Persons' then 'Two'
                when temp == '3 Persons' then 'Three'                
                when temp in ('4 Persons', '5 Persons', '6 Persons', '7 Persons','8 Persons','9 Persons','10 Persons','11 Persons') then 'More'
                else null 
              end""")).show()
```

While an [udf based solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73758233/2129801) offers more flexibility, the sql statements has a better performance as no Python code has to be run by Spark.